# Controlling responsive grid-area height in a CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to make responsive image gallery with CSS grid, however I have an issue with resizing.

[image: gallery image]

I would like bigger images to be the max height of the row, but while resizing window the smaller images extends grid as is visible on image.

How can I achieve this?

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.gallery-areas {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  grid-template-areas: "big-image-1 big-image-2 small-image-1 small-image-2" "big-image-1 big-image-2 small-image-3 small-image-4"
}

.image-1 {
  grid-area: big-image-1;
}

.image-2 {
  grid-area: big-image-2;
}

.image-3 {
  grid-area: small-image-1;
}

.image-4 {
  grid-area: small-image-2;
}

.image-5 {
  grid-area: small-image-3;
}

.image-6 {
  grid-area: small-image-4;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery-areas">
      <img class="image-1" src="https://dummyimage.com/389x435/000/fff" alt="">
      <img class="image-2" src="https://dummyimage.com/389x435/000/fff" alt="">
      <img class="image-3" src="https://dummyimage.com/389x201/000/fff" alt="">
      <img class="image-4" src="https://dummyimage.com/389x201/000/fff" alt="">
      <img class="image-5" src="https://dummyimage.com/389x201/000/fff" alt="">
      <img class="image-6" src="https://dummyimage.com/389x201/000/fff" alt="">
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know who voted to close this question as primarily opinion-based, but it is not at all an opinion-based question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that I understand your question is you want to make the bigger image to align with the smaller ones when screen is smaller.

The problem is that your image width is 100% so when the screen is smaller, the height(auto) is shorter because your image has reached the 100% mark.

I updated the height for image 1 and 2 to 100% and set the `max-width` of `img` to 100% instead of using width 100%. This way the bigger images can have height 100% and still have the proper ratio because width is defaulted to auto

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.gallery-areas {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  grid-template-areas: "big-image-1 big-image-2 small-image-1 small-image-2" "big-image-1 big-image-2 small-image-3 small-image-4"
}

.image-1 {
  grid-area: big-image-1;
}

.image-2 {
  grid-area: big-image-2;
}

.image-3 {
  grid-area: small-image-1;
}

.image-4 {
  grid-area: small-image-2;
}

.image-5 {
  grid-area: small-image-3;
}

.image-6 {
  grid-area: small-image-4;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.image-1, .image-2 {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery-areas">
      <img class="image-1" src="https://dummyimage.com/389x435/000/fff" alt="">
      <img class="image-2" src="https://dummyimage.com/389x435/000/fff" alt="">
      <img class="image-3" src="https://dummyimage.com/389x201/000/fff" alt="">
      <img class="image-4" src="https://dummyimage.com/389x201/000/fff" alt="">
      <img class="image-5" src="https://dummyimage.com/389x201/000/fff" alt="">
      <img class="image-6" src="https://dummyimage.com/389x201/000/fff" alt="">
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```